# Was throwing hammers as weapons common during European medieval combat?

Tags: middle-ages, weapons

I'm doing some research into the weapons of Dungeons and Dragons, and one of them is a 'light' hammer that you can throw. The description says it weighs 2lbs, if that helps narrow it down. I don't think throwing is the primary intended use, but it is very much supported by the rules.

I know about [Meteor Hammers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_hammer), and [throwing sticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throwing_stick) like the [Rungu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rungu_(weapon)) or [Iwisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwisa), but I'm not interested in those because they are outside of medieval Europe. I couldn't find any instances of warhammers or similar being thrown on Wikipedia, or from googling and I don't know where else to look.

Was anything like this ever done in real life medieval Europe, at least commonly enough to have been recorded?

Comment: IMHO this question **is** on-topic here. However, if you don't get a good answer, you might consider asking on the [martialarts.se](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/) site. In my experience they take their history seriously over there, and they *do* care about traditional European martial arts.

Comment: @T.E.D. I hadn't even considered that! Many thanks for the suggestion

Comment: The most famous thrown weapon during the Middle Ages was the francisca, an axe. And it seems it was used just before engaging the enemy hand-to-hand, to break the shields. I don't think a hammer would be able to do that, so the cost (losing your hand weapon) would be greater than the benefits (a concussion or a broken facial bone with an extraordinary lucky hit?).

Comment: @CarlosMartin interestingly the wikipedia article links to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurlbat which has been occasionally listed as a throwing club of some sort?

Comment: @Pureferret Yeah, but the wikipedia article says hurlbats only show in one sentence and we don't know if it was a warclub or a game.

Comment: The problem that often crops up in these sorts of discussions is the matter of intended use vs. improvised use. Given how common hammers would be, in all areas, during the middle-ages, it would be very surprising if they didn't crop up on a battlefield. Likewise, it would difficult to imagine that in all the battles that were fought that was never an occasion when someone threw a hammer at an opponent. How often that had to happen for someone to craft a weapon intended as a "throwing hammer" rather than a hammer that just happened to be throwable would be an interesting question in itself.

Comment: @CarlosMartin - Worse, it looks like every reference has a completely different definition.

Comment: Though I'd think that if it were used as a thrown weapon, one wouldn't want it to then possibly be just picked up by the enemy and then used against the attacker.  Most weapons, I'd think, would probably want to be designed to not be able to be more than single use implements, just to prevent the enemy from getting free weapons after initial use.

Comment: I'm invoking the rule of non-magical common sense. A "throwing hammer" makes none. After throwing at an enemy, you've just nicely disarmed yourself for the next one. And before you compare it to a "throwing knife" or a Shuriken, there is a vast difference between a knife or star, weighing ounces, and a hammer weighing pounds. (i.e. carrying 20 Shuriken is feasible, 20 throwing hammers and you're overloaded.)

Answer (score 11):

No. Why throw a blunt object, if you can just as easily throw something far more deadly, like a [throwing axe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throwing_axe), a [dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumbata) or even a [knife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throwing_knife)? The [Francisca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisca) **throwing** axe was a signature weapon of the Franks.

If you really want to throw something blunt, better use a rock. Just as  effective and much cheaper.

Warhammers had a very different purpose. You need to wield *(not throw!)* them, to inflict serious damage. They worked very well against armour. A warhammer was a close combat weapon. Throwing one was pretty much useless.

Don't forget, hammers (usually) have metal heads. Metal was expensive until at least halfway during the Middle Ages.

And lastly, [warhammers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_hammer) were mainly used by cavalry, almost always as a secondary or backup weapon. They would charge with a lance or sword, then switch to a warhammer when in close combat. (A lance wouldn't work in close combat.) It was not used by infantry, they had different weapons to work with.

A warhammer was a weapon that needed specialized training. Most infantry didn't have a lot of training. D&D is a fantasy game. A real warhammer was a relatively light weight slender weapon, definitely not a huge weapon as often depicted in D&D.

[image: preposterous unwieldy large hammer]

A real warhammer was very much like a modern claw hammer, with a longer handle, and one sharp end. In fact, a modern claw hammer would make a very good warhammer.

[image]

Comment: What you say makes absolute logical sense, but I'm reluctant to accept without some notion that we've tried to prove the negative, even if just by lack of evidence?

Comment: soldiers also typically carried only 1 war hammer after you throw it then what?

Comment: @ed.hank: The other side throws it back of course: and one gets to practice "*hammer catching*".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Isn't hammer throwing a sport? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_throw

Comment: @ed.hank I can envision a hammer at the end of a rope or chain. Cast and reel in, see what you catch :)

Comment: @jwenting Actually, if you add a loop through the hole of the hammer, it will be considered as a weapon in The Netherlands. You are allowed to have such a hammer in a toolbox, but if you happened to have one in your car, it is an illegal weapon.

Comment: @Jos I know, weapons laws here in the Netherlands are insane. Remember when several years ago they wanted to ban tyre irons and black clothes "because they're frequently used by criminals"?

Comment: @jwenting I served in the Marechaussee, 40 years ago. I know all about it. And boy, can I tell you some stories you won't believe! :-)

Comment: @Jos thank you for your service. I wanted to join the air force but was rejected during my conscription medical 35 or so years ago on health reasons.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Hammer throwing is a sporting event, so is caber tossing. I don't think any of the Highland Game events are based on combat.

Comment: @Pureferret There is no evidence for hammers being thrown. Missiles were arrows, bolts and javelins for the most part - slings still had some use, including staff slings which were slings mounted at the end of a pole using similar principles to the trebuchet. In dueling spears could be thrown or even swords, in one instance the pommel of a sword is unscrewed and thrown at the opponent, threaded tangs appeared in the late middle ages.

Answer (score 4):

> *If you really want to throw something blunt, better use a rock. Just as effective and much cheaper.*

I'd like to do an extended comment on this bit from [Jos's answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/66030/4615). It's on the right track, but we can take it further. There are much more efficient ways to hurl a blunt object than a warhammer.

A hammer is, effectively, a rock attached to a handle. The handle on a hammer provides leverage to give more torque to the "rock" on the end and hit things harder. Same with a throwing hammer, the handle lets you throw the "rock" harder and further.

But as Jos points out, this is rather expensive, and rather heavy to haul around. What if we could take the general concept of a handle to throw a rock and make it cheaper?

You get the [sling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon)). A piece of rope acts as the "handle" to throw a rock. Cheap, deadly, universal.

[image]

Going back further there was the [spear-thrower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear-thrower), which can just as easily throw stones.

[image]

It doesn't say that people *never* used throwing hammers in combat, but it does explain why they're not prevalent. Why throw the whole weapon when you can just throw the rock?

Comment: This is interesting side-knowledge, but not *really* relevant to the question?

Comment: @Pureferret This is a reason *why* they weren't common. The answer to "why didn't they use cool looking weapon X" is often because boring old Y was more efficient, and warfare is about efficiency. Like I said, an extended comment.

Comment: Another reason you forgot was that a hammer isn't exactly a well balanced piece of kit when it comes to weight distribution, making it have a rather unpredictable trajectory when thrown.

Comment: @Schwern, I thought about that, and didn't add it. Why? Because the question is specifically about HAMMER throwing. Not about throwing missiles in general. I fully agree with your answer, though in this case it's a bit off-topic.